# How to smooth a bezel

Tags: modeling

I have made a simple bezel in a cube.
When 3D printing the model the segments are very pronounced.
Is there a way to "smooth" these segments so that when printed they are gone?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please upload you images here and not on strange sites. I don’t what to press any button on that site.

Comment: Your topology is very bad, I didn't know you could even print that, there are faces overlapping everywhere etc... your shape is rather simple, you should re-do it properly

Comment: Hello and welcome Joe. Please use only https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com for blend files, and the builtin tools for images

Comment: If I could of found a "built-in tool" to upload my picture I would of used it. After searching around for over 15 minutes I assumed there was no such tool.

Comment: @Moonbots Please explain how to do it properly. All I did was select 2 lines, press CTRL-B and make a bezel. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Searching](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=stackexchange+image+upload) returns [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498) as the first link.

Comment: @moonboots is right. Best to remake